# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code. Bugsnag source map upload connection timed out

Tags: react-native, rocket.chat, bugsnag, white-labelling

I am trying to white label this github repo.

https://github.com/RocketChat

Here is the white label guide that the RocketChat has provided.

https://developer.rocket.chat/mobile-app/mobile-app-white-labelling/ios-app-white-labelling

This library is for react native. I am facing this issue when I try to run the project.

The project is failing the build process with this error.

```
    > PhaseScriptExecution Upload\ source\ maps\ to\ Bugsnag
    > /Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RocketChatRN-adkttzebukwzincfwduuaihsdgwi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RocketChatRN.build/Debug-iphoneos/RocketChatRN.build/Script-88055964DAAE45B1A4886C27.sh
    > (in target 'RocketChatRN' from project 'RocketChatRN')
    >     cd /Users/macbook/Rocket.Chat.ReactNative-develop/ios
    >     /bin/sh -c /Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RocketChatRN-adkttzebukwzincfwduuaihsdgwi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RocketChatRN.build/Debug-iphoneos/RocketChatRN.build/Script-88055964DAAE45B1A4886C27.sh
    > 
    > ℹ Preparing upload of React Native source map (dev / ios) › Reading
    > source map
    > "/var/folders/sz/jj5jd6j54kd505vxsyxvlk1h0000gn/T//bcd7e9d7452d009ff844f5acf22fb2f3-main.jsbundle.map"
    > › Reading bundle file
    > "/Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RocketChatRN-adkttzebukwzincfwduuaihsdgwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/main.jsbundle"
    > ℹ Applying transformations to source map › Ensuring sourcesContent
    > field is populated › Stripping project root from sources › Initiating
    > upload to "https://upload.bugsnag.com/react-native-source-map"

 ERROR  The request timed out.

 Connection timed out

  at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/macbook/Rocket.Chat.ReactNative-develop/node_modules/@bugsnag/source-maps/dist/Request.js:190:21)
  at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28)
  at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
  at TLSSocket.emitRequestTimeout (node:_http_client:771:9)
  at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28)
  at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:539:35)
  at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (node:net:516:8)
  at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
  at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

I have tried to remove the source map upload. See Screen Shot 1 [image: Disabling the source map upload by bugsnag.]

It keeps on giving the same error still.

It says bugsnag source map failed to upload and is timing out. I have no prior experience with React Native and I am just trying to white label their code. So any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Would you be able to check your package.json file for which version of @bugsnag/source-maps you are using? If you are using anything prior to v2.3.0 of @bugsnag/source-maps you could try updating as it has now increased the default timeout and made some other improvements.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, (M1 Mac only I guess)

Go to the target you want to archive

1. `Build settings` ---> `Architectures` ---> `Excluded Architectures`
2. Delete `arm64`

---

Also another possible reason could be that Xcode is using an outdated version of Node

By default, Xcode will use the Node binary located at /usr/local/bin/node. Check its version by running:

```
/usr/local/bin/node -v 
node -v
```

If the first command outputs an older version of Node, simply delete it and replace it with a symlink to the newer one:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node
ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node
```